# Best pick front-end framework for building large scale web applications?

Tags: javascript

I'm planning to use BackboneJS or EmberJS to do a big rework on a large scale web application.

Also, I'm open for some frontend frameworks as well.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend AngularJS (https://angularjs.org/)

Comment: Currently I have some learning curve with AngularJS. May I know your reasons why you suggest it?

Comment: Obviously every framework has its pros and cons, I would recommend AngularJS because it works best for me. But to give you a better understanding of what might work best for you I would recommend this article (http://www.airpair.com/js/javascript-framework-comparison)